# How can i get indication when the user get a phone call?

Tags: android

How can i get indication when the user receives incoming call?

I also want to get the indication when the application is not running.

?

Comment: [See this answer][1]

You'll need a BroadcastReceiver and an <input-filter> in your manifest


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2958800/service-and-a-broadcastreceiver

Answer (score 0):

Hi for this you have to use broadcast reciever

```
public class TestServiceReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {
    TelephonyManager telephony = (TelephonyManager) context
    .getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

    int state = telephony.getCallState();
    String incomingNumber =
        intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);

    switch (state) {
    case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:

        Log.d("@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@TestServiceReceiver", "IDLE");
        break;
    case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:

        Log.d("@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@TestServiceReceiver", "OFFHOOK");
        break;
    case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:

        Log.d("@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@TestServiceReceiver", "RINGING");
        break;
    }
}
```

And in manifest file you have to declare receiver

```
<receiver android:name=".TestServiceReceiver"><intent-filter><action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE"/></intent-filter></receiver>
```

now declear some permissions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PRIVILEGED"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_PHONE_STATE"/>
```

finally you can do anything with your phone calls

Comment: Thanks for your response.  i have tried this, but when the application is not running i don't get the intent, how can i get the broadcast even if my app is not running?

Comment: What do you want to do start you application from this broadcast receiver or want to just listen broadcast every time